# Consider the patch $\sigma(u,v)=(u,v,uv)$. Find the principal curvatures and principal directions

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

Ok, so I’m able to find the coefficients of the first and second fundamental forms. And then I’m able to find the Gaussian and Mean curvature

$H=\frac{-2uv}{(1+u^2+v^2)^{3/2}}$

$K=\frac{-1}{(1+u^2+v^2)^2}$

I then use the relationships

$H=k_1+k_2$ and

$K=k_1k_2$

To find principal curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$. I get stuck on the algebra here.

Is someone able to help me find $k_1,k_2$?

Once i find $k_1$ and $k_2$, then I’m not sure how to find the principal directions

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to find the matrix of the shape operator (Weingarten map) by computing $\text{I}^{-1}\text{II}$. Then find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. You'll need the quadratic formula, but that's not bad!